# Angular material : passing data from one component to another

Tags: angular, angular-material

I have two components, first component `ShowDepComponent` has the `ngFor` to collect the `DapatmentName` and `DepartmentID`. I would like to pass these `DepartmentName` to another component `AddEditDepComponent` when triggering the click event, `DepartmentName` should pass to another component `AddEditDepComponent`.

How to do that? Thanks.

ShowDepComponent:

- HTML

```
   <ng-container *ngFor="let eachone of GetDepartList">
     <mat-grid-tile [style.background]="'#F1EBBA'">
       {{eachone.DepartmentId}}
     </mat-grid-tile>
     <mat-grid-tile [(ngModel)]="DepartmentName" [style.background]="'#F1EBBA'">
       {{eachone.DepartmentName}}
     </mat-grid-tile>
     <mat-grid-tile  [style.background]="'#F1EBBA'">
       <button  (click) = "EditDeprt()" class="Options" mat-stroked-button> Edit</button>
       <button (click) = "DelDeprt()" mat-stroked-button> Delete </button>
```

- .ts file:

```js
  DepartmentName: any;
  Department: any;
  EditDeprt() {
    this.Dialog.open(AddEditDepComponent, {
      height: '200px',
      width: '400px',
      data: {DepartmentName: this.DepartmentName} 
  });
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 1):

What you have done so far is correct, The only thing remaining is to get the `Department` name in your `AddEditDepComponent`.

So in your `AddEditDepComponent`, You can inject the data that you sent from `ShowDepComponent` into its constructor. You already sent your data using the `dialog.open()` method.

All you have to do get that data in`AddEditDepComponent` .ts :

```js
 constructor(
     @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any,
 ){}

 ngOnInit(): void {
 console.log(this.data.DepartmentName);
 }
```